# Cannot manage association Account belongs_to User and Account has_many users with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have a DB schema where an account has_many users but the account also belongs_to a single user which is the admin user of the account.

I express this relation by having an admin_user_id column into the accounts table.

In terms of associations I would like to be able to write both :
1) user.accounts to get all accounts that have been created by a specific user
2) account.users to get all the users that have been added to a specific account

2) works already but I cant get to make 1) work.

I tried adding   `belongs_to :admin_user, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "admin_user_id"` to my Account model but it doesnt work :

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base

  # associations
  has_many :users
  has_many :hotels
  belongs_to :admin_user, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "admin_user_id"

end
```

How can I make this work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In User Model

```
has_many :created_accounts, class_name: "Account", foreign_key: "user_id", inverse_of: :admin
has_many :accounts
```

In Account model

```
belongs_to :admin, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "user_id"
has_many :users
```

Then to find all accounts created by a certain user do : `user.created_accounts`

To find who create a specific account do : `account.admin`.

And finally with `account.users` you should find all users that belongs to that account.

Comment: Thanks this is working but I dont really get the inverse_of: :admin